# PHP function to replace a HTML tag (e.g. meta description) using preg_replace

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

Can someone help me get this function to work? The function should accept `$HTMLstr` -- a whole page of HTML stuffed into a string that already contains a meta description in the form of:

```
<meta name="description" content="This will be replaced"/>
```

along with `$content` which is the string that should replace "This will be replaced". I thought I was close with this function, but it doesn't quite work.

```
function HTML_set_meta_description ($HTMLstr, $content) {
$newHTML = preg_replace('/<meta name="description"(.*)"\/>/is', "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"$content\"/>", $HTMLstr);
return ($newHTML);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Here's the working function.

```
function HTML_set_meta_description ($HTMLstr, $content) {
// assumes meta format is exactly <meta name="description" content="This will be replaced"/>
$newHTML = preg_replace('/<meta name="description" content="(.*)"\/>/i','<meta name="description" content="' . $content . '" />', $HTMLstr);
return ($newHTML);
```

}

Comment: Use a DOM Parser instead. [**Why**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Also, it looks like your your function will `exit` before it gets to the replace?

Comment: Oops! removed debugging code. I promise that wasn't the problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DOMDocument` is recommended as already an answer, however if you're struggling with a regular expression, then I might help you out. You might try this instead:

```
return preg_replace('/<meta name="description" content="(.*)"\/>/i','<meta name="description" content="Something replaced" />', $HTMLstr);
```

Comment: That works, thanks! (BTW your example switched out name= for content=)

Comment: Yep, sorry I misspelled an attribute

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know that the `<meta>` will be provided in a consistent format (which is difficult to know unless you actually have control over the HTML) you will have a very tough time constructing a working regex.  Take these examples:

```
<meta content="content" name="description">
<meta content = 'content' name = 'description' />
<meta name= 'description' content ="content"/>
```

These are all valid, but the regex that would handle them would be very complex.  Something like:

```
@<meta\s+name\s*=\s*('|")description\1\s+content\s*('|")(.*?)\2\s+/?>@
```

...and that doesn't even account for the attributes being in a different order.  There may have been something else I didn't think of as well.

On the other hand using a parser such as DOMDocument may be very expensive, especially if your HTML is large.  If you *can* depend on a consistent format for the `<meta>` you want to use `.*?` instead of `.*` to capture the content.  `.*?` makes the search reluctant so it will stop at the *first* quote as opposed to the last -- there are likely to be many other quotes throughout the HTML document.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($HTMLstr);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("meta") as $tag) {
    if (stripos($tag->getAttribute("name"), "description") !== false) {
        $tag->setAttribute("content", $content);
    }
}
return $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: The HTML string is coming from my own template, so I can exactly predict the <meta> format to match my example. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @Canton not much ... does changing `.*` to `.*?` not fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked preg_replace and im late to answer but look at this, is it that you are looking for...

```
<?php
function meta_desc( $content = null ){
    $desc = 'This will be replaced ';
    if( $content ){
        $desc = $content;
    }
    return '<meta name="description"
content=" '. $desc .' "/>';
}
?>
```

Trust me its faster than that. I think you should use this function.